# Big development teams can't handle a single CSS style sheet?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am currently in a 5-7 large development team creating a really large website with lots of pages and features.

I feel like we are in such a situation where a developer can change the style sheet to suit his own needs, but is unaware of the 1000 places where it probably change it for something else. I cannot blame him either, since I know it's hard to check everything.

It's a total mess.

I know that using one single style sheet file saves bandwidth and prevents duplicated code and maintenance, but I cant help wondering - is using style sheets a good idea for big sites, or should it be more object/element oriented.

Let's say you forget about the crazy large CSS and you define the CSS on each element instead. So each time you render a GreenBuyButton, it has the "style='bla bla bla'" on it. And this is pretty much done for all elements.

This will increase the bandwidth, but it will not create duplicated code.

Could this be a good idea or how does really large teams work on a single website do with CSS to avoid it being a mess?

Comment: That is a terrible idea and is _guaranteed_ to produce repeated code. Think about it for a second.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Practices - CSS Stylesheet Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956996/best-practices-css-stylesheet-formatting)

Comment: Are you using some version control for your stylesheets?

Comment: Yes, the CSS is under version control.

Comment: Lèse majesté: Please explain why this would duplicate code?

Comment: @corgrath, how would it not duplicate code? You are re-typing style="something" for each element you wish to style... 2 buttons on a page same style = duplicate

Comment: @corgath: The reason stylesheets are used is because it's impractical to have to change the style of every single element every time you want to make changes to the presentation of your site. The only conceivable way you could use inline styles without duplicating manually-written code is if you hard-code the styles into some kind of UI-builder class. And even then you're going to be duplicating CSS wherever you have different elements that have similar styles plus embedding CSS in your server-side code. It's just a bad idea.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you create multiple CSS sheets depending on the area of the site?

- blog.css
- accounts.css
- shopping.css

Then you could have a serverside script (say PHP) combine all CSS into 1 sheet which will get you the same result of 1 small file (could use a minimizer as well).

Check your overall site with a CSS checker to find duplicates (css defined) and manage it that way.

Otherwise communication is key between your team, who develops what, and so people don't duplicate CSS definitions. A master CSS keeper would be best suited to manage the CSS styles, besides your team should have an agreed upon style and not go rouge creating their own unique styles.

Comment: This wouldn't fix anything, I even think this would make it worse since then we would have to maintain multiple CSS files.

Comment: how so? you simplify the process from a giant file to something that is broken down per team member / task / process.  Your issue as a whole is a lack of proper planning and communication.

Comment: this is the only approach that makes any sense +1

Comment: The one thing I don't like about this, is you don't know the order of application of styles. If the style sheets are reversed in one file, styles will override differently (if the same selectors are defined in two). This could prompt a dev to "Fix" this issue by changing some styling rules, instead of ensuring the ordering of the CSS files are consistent across pages

Comment: We dont have different "areas" of the website. Just extremly alot of buttons and everyone is fitting the global CSS to fit their own needs. If you are planing to merge all CSS-files into one for the website visitor, why not just use 1 CSS to begin with? Then you avoid people reusing class-names, etc.

Comment: I'm one developer working on a huge site with many pages, functions and features; after some time I discarded the use of once huge style sheet (10,000 lines+) and went with "modular" stylesheets, using PHP to combine them all into one sheet, minifying it. Makes it a lot easier to keep everything separate. Change logs also help to keep on top of the "doubling up of code".

Comment: I find one large file organized and broken into sections via comment blocks much easier to troubleshoot that multiple files.

Comment: each of your files should more or less scope all selectors down to a specific area. If you guys are running into that many collisions, you aren't using css selectors properly.

Answer (score 8):

My recommendation would be to use the CSS rules on specifity to help you.  For each CSS that is not global, put an activate selector on, for example

```
.user-list .p {
    font-size: 11pt
}

.login-screen .p {
   font-size: 12pt
}
```

This will make it easy to identify what rules are for which pages, and which rules are global.  That way developers can stick to their own set of styles, and no mess up anyone else's.

Comment: So basically, its the idea i described above with element oriented css? One "style" per element and not everything in a large list?

Comment: Well, you can also break it down, and have as many levels as you want, so you cold have for instance

.user-list .button-panel .cancel-button {..}

Use these rules to develop a CSS heirarchy, then all devs know what styles are for where, and you won't have any accidental styling of elements outside of styling scope.  Ultimately, if the dev knows where the style is applied, your less likely to have issues with devs changing styles they are not supposed to.

Comment: @corgrath it sounded like you were advocating inline styles on each element and not using an external stylesheet. What Zoidberg is suggesting is using classes, ids and css selectors in your stylesheet better, to set some basic styles and then override them in specific areas, it's completely different.

Answer (score 3):

Change how you write CSS.

Instead fo treating every area of the website like a specific piece of markup that needs styling, start defining broad classes.

Enforce some rules.  Like, "All `<ul>` have a specific look for this project."  If there are multiple ways you want to style an element, start using classes.  This will keep your website looking uniform throughout.  Uniformity reduces broken layout.

Create building block classes like a "framework" of sorts.  This has helped me so often that I never start a project without doing this first.  Take a look at the jquery-ui themeroller framework to give you the idea.  Here's an example:

```
.icon        { display:block;width:16px;height:16px;}
.icon-green  { background:url(/green.png);}
.icon-blue   { background:url(/blue.png);}
```

Then on the elements:

```
<span class="icon icon-green"></span>
<span class="icon icon-blue"></span>
```

Breaking your styles up into their building blocks like this and using multiple classes on the element will keep your team members from having to change styles to suit their needs.  If a particular styling quirk is not available they can define a new set of classes.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example of how I used this method:  [Movingcost.com](http://www.movingcost.com).  Huge website, multiple different sections and pages, and only 252 lines of uncompressed css.  Actually, these days I break things down further than I did on the movingcost project.  I probably would have gone through those elements at the bottom of the stylesheet and figured out how to combine some of those into classes.

Comment: Done well, layered classes are awesome.  Done poorly, you end up with one style attribute in each class.  Execution is key.

Comment: You're right, it's a balancing act.  Sometimes a single style attribute is preferred (I like to do this `.blue { color:#00f;}`) but usually you should cluster them in logical groups.

Answer (score 2):

### Multiple CSS files and combine in code

While doing development I found out that doing it the following way seems to be reasonable and well suited to development teams:

2. Don't put any styling into HTML. Maintainability as well as lots of head scratching why certain things don't display as expected will be really bad.
3. Have one (or few of them) global CSS that defines styles for global parts. Usually defines everything in template/master. Can be bound to master page or to generic controls used on majority of pages.
4. Have per-page/per-control CSS files when they are actually needed. Most of the pages won't need them, but developers can write them
5. Have these files well structured in folders
6. use naming and formatting guidelines so everyone will be able to write/read code
7. Write server side code taht will combine multiple CSS files into a single one to save bandwith.

You can as well automate some other tasks like auto adding per-page CSS files if they're named the same as pages themselves.

Doing it this way will make it easier to develop, since single CSS files will be easier to handle due to less content and you will have less code merging conflicts, because users will be working on separate functionality most of the time.

**But** there's not feasible way of automating *CSS unit tests* that would make sure that changing an existing CSS setting won't break other parts of your site.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite override trick is to assign the id attribute on the `<body>` of each page.  It's an easy way to make page specific changes without breaking out a separate stylesheet file.

You could have the following html

```
<body id="home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</body>

<body id="about">
  <h1>About</h1>
</body>
```

And use the following css overrides

```
h1 {color: black}
#about h1 {color: green}
```

The home page gets the default css while the about gets overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Using style sheets on large sites is an excellent idea. However, it only really works when you apply your team standards to the style. It makes sense to have a singular template controller that links your style sheet(s). It also makes sense to appoint someone on the team as "keeper of the style" who all changes to the style sheet should go through before making substantive changes.

Once the style standards are agreed upon and defined, then all of the controls in the site should implement the styles defined. This allows developers to get out of the business of coding to style and simply coding to the standard. Inputs are inputs, paragraphs are paragraphs, and floating divs are a headache.

The key is standardization within the team and compliance by all of the developers. I currently lead a team site that has upwards of 30 style sheets to control everything for layout, fonts, data display, popups, menu and custom controls. We do not have any of these issues because the developers very rarely need to edit the style sheet directly because the standards are clearly designed and published.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the name.  The reason it's called cascading style sheets is because multiple can be combined and there are decent rules defined on which one takes preference.

First of all, doing all your styling inline is a ridiculous idea.  Not only will it waste bandwidth like nothing else, it will also result in inconsistency.  Think about it for a while: why would changing a line of css 'break' another page?  That indicates your css selectors are poorly chosen.

Here are my suggestions:

- use one css file for the basic site look.  This css file is written by people doing mainly design, and as a result the site has a consistent look.  It defines the basic colors, layout and such.
- use another css file per 'section'.  For instance, a 'shopping' section will use components that are nowhere else on the site.  Use that to define section-specific stuff
- put page-specific styling directly in the page (in the header).  If this section becomes too big, you're doing something wrong
- put exceptional styling directly on the components.  If you're doing the same thing three times, abstract it out and use a class instead.
- choose your classes wisely and use the semantics for naming.  *'selectedSalesItem'* is good *'greenBold'* is bad
- if a developer changes a stylerule and it breaks the rest of the site, why did he need to change it?  Either it's an exceptional thing for what he's working on (and should be inlined) or it was basically broken on the rest of the site as well, and should be fixed anyway.

If your css files become too big to handle, you can split them up and merge them server-side, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to define CSS for each element because if you ever need to make a change that affects many elements one day, say the looks of all the buttons or headers, you will be doing a lot of Search/Replace. And how to check if you forgot to update one rule to keep your site consistent?

Stephen touched on a very strong point in CSS. You can assign multiple classes to an element.
You should define some basic rules that "ordinary" developers can't touch. They will provide the consistency through the site.
Then developers can assign an extra class to personalize any property. I wouldn't assign more than two classes though: a global and a personalized.

Considering you already have this huge stylesheet in your hands, I'm not sure how you will pick which one of the 7 developers will have to sit down through a month and organize it. That is probably going to be hard part.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to extract your website's default element styling and page structure into a separate stylesheet. That way people understand changing those rules affects the entire site's appearance/structure, not just the page they're working on.

Once you do that, all you really need to do is document / comment all of your code. A person is a lot less likely to write duplicate code in a well-documented stylesheet, and that is a fact.